# Filtering byte stream efficiently before converting to numpy array / pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, buffer, bytestream

I'm looking for guidance on how to efficiently filter out unneeded parts of my data before converting to a numpy array and/or pandas dataframe. Data is delivered to my program as string buffers (each record separately), and I'm currently using `np.frombuffer` to construct an array once all records are retrieved.

The problem I'm having is that individual records can be quite long, thousands of fields, and sometimes I only want a small subset of them. Filtering out these unneeded fields adds steps and significantly slows down the data import though.

Without any filtering, my current process is:

```
# assume some function here that retrieves one record at a time and appends it to 'data'

data = [b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?one     \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Y@',
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@two     \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00i@',
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08@three   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0r@',
        b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10@four    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00y@']

final_data = b''.join(data)

arr = np.frombuffer(final_data, dtype=struct_dtypes)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

# dataframe
    n1     ch     n2
0  1.0    one  100.0
1  2.0    two  200.0
2  3.0  three  300.0
3  4.0   four  400.0
```

My current solution for filtering is essentially:

```
final_data = b''.join(b''.join(buffer[offset: offset + 8] for offset in [0, 16]) for buffer in data)

struct_dtypes = np.dtype([('n1', 'd'), ('n2', 'd')])
arr = np.frombuffer(final_data, dtype=struct_dtypes)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

    n1     n2
0  1.0  100.0
1  2.0  200.0
2  3.0  300.0
3  4.0  400.0
```

That middle step to slice and rejoin each record makes filtering slower than just reading everything. If I construct the full array first and then return only the specified columns, isn't that just a waste of memory? What's an appropriate way to read only the portions of the string buffers I want?

**Update using accepted answer**

```
struct_dtypes = np.dtype({'names': ['n1', 'ch'],
                          'formats': ['d', '8V'],
                          'offsets': [0, 8],
                          'itemsize': 24})

final_data = b''.join(data)

arr = np.frombuffer(final_data, dtype=struct_dtypes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an offset for each field during [dtype construction](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types):

```
struct_dtypes = np.dtype({'names': ['n1', 'n2'], 'formats': ['d', 'd'], 'offsets': [0, 16]})
```

or

```
struct_dtypes = np.dtype({'n1': ('d', 0), 'n2': ('d', 16)})
```

**Update** (see comments below):
If you don't read the last element in the record, you need to specify the `itemsize`:

```
struct_dtypes = np.dtype({'names': ['n1', 'ch'],
                          'formats': ['d', '8V'],
                          'offsets': [0, 8],
                          'itemsize': 24})
```

Comment: Depending on the field subset I use, I'm getting an error: buffer size must be a multiple of element size

Comment: for what subset do you get this error? does the subset include strings?

Comment: `struct_dtypes = np.dtype({'n1': ('d', 0), 'ch': ('8V', 8)})` - yes, it contains strings, but I'm importing them as void types for now.

Comment: it works if I use `np.frombuffer(count=1)`, but I need to do testing on overall speed because converting each record separately and then concatenating might be expensive.

Comment: so it seems slicing each record to the appropriate end position is sufficient and not very expensive, at least compared to extracting many slices and rejoining as I was doing earlier. Thanks!

Comment: @StevenS please see my updated answer for this case, so that you can read the whole buffer in one run